# Calculate the bandwidth utilization of periodic traffic

Tags: networking, routes, ethernet, bandwidth

I am so confused about the concepts of bandwidth and link-speed, are they the same? Also, confused about the bandwidth utilization. Is there any reference formula for bandwidth utilization?

An example case:

```
nodeA --> switch1 --> nodeB # nodeA sends L bits traffic to nodeB every P seconds. Link-speed is S.
```

How to calculate the bandwidth utilization of egress of switch1?

Comment: The bandwidth is dictated by the interface. For example, the bandwidth of a 100 Mbps interface is 100 Mbps, meaning the bits are serialized a 100 Mbps. Some people confuse throughput with bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

def : S = L/P = bandwidth = MB/s.

Comment: Could you please explain more? And, S is the maximum link speed that is a fixed value.

Comment: You are confusing bandwidth with throughput. The bandwidth of a link is fixed, and it is measured in Mbps, but throughput is variable and measured in MBps. The throughput will  always be something less than the bandwidth.